# What type of evidence to prove continuous residence

Tags: immigration, naturalization

Specifically, I am asking about the category "Your immediate family remained in the U.S." My brother and his wife remained in the US during the time I was absent. What evidence should I provide to prove that he was present in the US during the time I was absent?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about immigration bureaucratic requirements, not the law or legal process. Asking on Expatriates Stack Exchange will likely provide better results.

Comment: Unless your brother is dependent on you, he probably won't count. [immediate family](https://my.uscis.gov/exploremyoptions/us_petition_for_immediate_relative) is spouse, parents, minor children.

Comment: I am a dependent on my brother. Does that count?